# Nodejs. Unknown symbols in browser

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using express plugin in nodeJS

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
           res.render('main', {
               pageTitle: "заголовок",
               header: "хедер"
           });
    });
```

I set jade for view engine

```
app.set('view engine','jade');
```

And this is my simple jade view

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1= header
```

But i get unknown symbols in my browser.

http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/FY0W.png

Comment: First method of debugging is to try different encodings in your browser. In Chrome it's burger menu -> More Tools -> Encoding. In Safari it's View -> Text Encoding etc. Keep on changing until you find an encoding that works. Once you've found the encoding set the correct charset in the Content-type header.

Comment: Check response with curl/wget

Answer (score 0):

In your jade code , try to specify charset

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title= pageTitle
  body
    h1= header
```